# NugetPackages that are missing on this pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Please help I have no more ideas that I can try to get rid of this error
thanks in advance

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.2.10\build\net46\MSTest.TestAdapter.props. DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer.UnitTests C:\Users\markus.meissl\Desktop\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer.UnitTests\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer.UnitTests.csproj   240
```

Comment: Why not install the packages

Comment: `nuget restore`

Comment: Packages are installed

Comment: I make a restore i deleted the folder and than restore but nothing Changes

Comment: look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/Package-restore-troubleshooting for resolved your problem

Comment: For me, the same code snippet has several lines of implementation underneath

Comment: I see this error most commonly when a project was added to a different solution than it was originally created in, or the relative path from the project to the solution has changed (for example, project directory moved, or solution file moved), and the project uses packages.config. In these cases, opening Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, and running `Update-Package -Reinstall` on the affected project(s) often fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter this issue, the first step is to try to use restore operation. If the restore step doesn't work, you could try to check the compatibility of the packages, sometimes the error comes from the package's inner configuration.

You could use this to clean and rebuild your project to ensure that everything is properly configured:

```
   dotnet clean
   dotnet build
```

Also, sometimes the issue may come from the project settings, please check the .csproj file on your side. Any way, please show more information when encounter this issue.

Comment: I believe that the "nuget packages have not been restored" message only happens for packages.config projects, and the `dotnet` CLI only works for SDK style projects, which only support PackageReference. Hence, I'm afraid that I don't think that `dotnet restore` or `dotnet build` will work.

Comment: C:\Users\markus.meissl\Desktop\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer.UnitTests\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer.UnitTests.csproj(252,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\DAMLIB.ResultAnalyzer\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.2.10\build\net46\MSTest.TestAdapter.props.

put in the file the .props file is exist